# Independent event proof

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics, proof

I'm doing a stats past paper for my first year exam, and I'm having some trouble answering the following question. Could someone please help me?

Thanks

'Show that if 3 events $\{A, B, C\}$ are independent, then $(A \cup B)$ and $C$ are independent as well'